# Null checkboxes are not checked on load of SSRS report in browser

Tags: reporting-services, null

I have a report with several date parameters, each with a NULL default value.  In ReportBuilder, the report runs and the null checkboxes start out checked, automatically.  When I pull this report up in a browser, the checkboxes are no longer checked and it prompts me for values for all those parameters.

This question was previously asked, but the answer seems to be out of date.  Can someone please advise.

Thank you.

Comment: My first guess would be that this is not the initial deployment of the report and the old defaults are still in place. The easiest thing to do is to edit the report direct on the server and change the parameter defaults or, delete the report from the server and redeploy it . Once a report is deployed, the default values do not get updated by subsequent deployments, I'm not sure if this is a bug or by design but that's how it works.

Comment: That was it!  Deleting and republishing solved it.  Thank you.  Never would've occurred to me to do that.

Comment: No problem. I'll add this as an answer so other can find it in the future. If you can mark it as accepted that will help.

Answer (score 0):

My first guess would be that this is not the initial deployment of the report and the old defaults are still in place.

The easiest thing to do is to edit the report direct on the server and change the parameter defaults

Alternatively, delete the report from the server and redeploy it .

*Once a report is deployed, the default values do not get updated by subsequent deployments, I'm not sure if this is a bug or by design but that's how it works.*

Comment: Don't see an option to "accept" as answer.

Comment: It's the checkmark, to the left under the vote up/down buttons.